# Rails query - latest Post for each day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

A `User` has_many `Posts`.  I want to retrieve the latest Post for each day (using `created_at`), ignoring other posts that may have been written earlier.  Another way to pose this question might to ask for a each top salary earning employee by department - same thing I think.

How do I write this query in Rails (4.0 preferably)?  I think it has something to do with `group` and `maximum` but I can't seem to get it.  Is there a way to do it without resorting to SQL?

To clarify, what I'd like returned is an array of post objects that are the last ones written on their respective date.

Thanks!

Comment: What RDMBS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, sqlite)? The SQL can be perfected for the right backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clean, but this works in Rails 3 (taken from a Book model in my case) using PostgreSQL syntax for truncating the created_at to the date:

```
max_created_at_list = Book.select("max(created_at) as created_at").group("date_trunc('day',created_at)")
last_books = Book.where(:created_at => max_created_at_list)
```

... or just:

```
Book.where(:created_at =>Book.select("max(created_at) as created_at").group("date_trunc('day',created_at)"))
```

You'd want an index on created_at for large data sets, and either created_at to be constrained to not null at the database level or an "is not null" predicate if the RDBMS you use does not index nulls (eg. Oracle)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. You can convert this to AREL syntax as needed:

```
SELECT posts.created_at, *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(created_at) AS max_order_date FROM posts
    GROUP BY DATE(posts.created_at)
) AS last_postings ON last_postings.max_order_date = posts.created_at
ORDER BY DATE(created_at) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

AREL syntax might be:

```
join_sql = <<-SQL
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(created_at) AS max_order_date FROM posts
        GROUP BY DATE(posts.created_at)
    ) AS last_postings ON last_postings.max_order_date = posts.created_at
SQL
Post.joins(join_sql).order('DATE(created_at) DESC')
```

Remove the `LIMIT` as it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Post.select("user_id, max(created_at) as created_at").group(:user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this retrieves the last post date for each user - without the post records.  What I'd like returned is an array of post objects that are the last ones written on their respective date.