# How to get latest comments from each post in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a standard blog models, user, posts and comments. How can I query for 1 latest comment of **each** post of custom user?

I know we can connect users with comments through posts, but this does not give me an idea how it can help.

DB structure

```
users: id, name, created_at, updated_at

posts: id, title, created_at, updated_at, user_id

comments: id, text, created_at, updated_at, user_id, post_id
```

Comment: You should share more like the table structure or some ruby code for this question to be complete.

Comment: Molfar, how you define latest? Last 5 comments? Comments since 3 hours ago? And like @RaymondNijland suggests, you should add the table structure

Comment: Last - I mean recent, ordered by some field, in this case - by created_at

Comment: @Molfar what do you expect to get? What kind of structure?
Something like this: `[post1: [new_comments_post1], post2: [new_comments_post2], post3: []]`. Or only the comments?
What do you mean by  recent? 
You should be more clear

Comment: if your structure is `user` has many `comments`, and if you want to get the latest first, sort the comments by its created_at first like this `user.order('created_at DESC').comments`

Comment: Do you mean "for a given post, list the latest X comments" or "for a given post list the latest post for each unique user" or "for a given post of a given user show the latest comment" ?

Comment: I need to get one most recent comment for each of user's posts.

Comment: See for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882073/mysql-select-max-date-inside-a-join-statement/17882188#17882188 If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Do you want the latest comments for a specific user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails query - latest Post for each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030235/rails-query-latest-post-for-each-day)

Answer (score -3):

If your structure is `user` has many `comments`, and if you want to get the latest first, sort the comments by its created_at first like this:

`user.order('created_at DESC').comments`

In your `post` model:

```
def latest_comment
    comments.order('created_at DESC').first
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    post.latest_comment
end
```

Comment: this statement cat return multiple comments of same post. And I need to get one recent comment of each post.

Comment: if you need to get just one comment for each post, you could define a method in post where get the latest comment then iterate to every posts you will display.